# Copy tables from one mysql to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database where orders from woocommerce are comeing.
I also have a crm system where all projects are stored in another mysql db.

I'm working on crone script, which will check every hour e-store db and take new orders and instert it to crm database as projects.

F.ex. orderID from ShopDB has to go to projectID to crm DB etc.

Which tool schould I use or how php script should looks like? The most important to me is to avoid duplicates. So every time script should check what was the last exported/imported order. It also can not every time export and replace all table, because I will modify each order in crm. So it should only copy new orders.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL replication, so every order will direct replicated to your crm,
only enable binlog on the shop DB and setup the replication on the crm db server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any tools but have you considered using [`Replication`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html). You can set up a `Transactional Replication` and so every new transaction (`insert/update/delete`) will get replicated to the secondary CRM DB as well.